# How can I restore my faith?

Tags: imaan

I never see Israel-Palestine war news, pictures, or videos. because I cannot stand those.

Today, I saw some videos of some Palestinian kids in a totally unrelated video on YouTube.

After that, I have a feeling that I am losing my faith in “Allah.” Because I am having a feeling that the kind of pain and suffering the little kids are going through could not have been possible if anything called “Allah” was out there somewhere.

How can I restore my faith?